# How to rename the .html file by its previous directory names using linux command?

Tags: linux

---

Here is my directory structure i want to rename the .html files only under the named directory rev by its previous two directory names .How can i do it using command?

```
    prj3
    |-- blk1
    |   |-- blk1.config
    |   |-- blk1.html
    |   |-- checklist13
    |   |   |-- checklist13.config
    |   |   |-- checklist13.html
    |   |   |-- checklist13.html~
    |   |   `-- rev2
    |   |       |-- rev2.config
    |   |       `-- rev2.html
    |   |-- checklist14
    |   |   |-- checklist14.config
    |   |   |-- checklist14.html
    |   |   |-- checklist14.html~
    |   |   `-- rev5
    |   |       |-- rev5.config
    |   |       |-- rev5.html
    |   |       `-- rev5.html~
```

Expected output:

```
    prj3
    |-- blk1
    |   |-- blk1.config
    |   |-- blk1.html
    |   |-- checklist13
    |   |   |-- checklist13.config
    |   |   |-- checklist13.html
    |   |   |-- checklist13.html~
    |   |   `-- rev2
    |   |       |-- rev2.config
    |   |       `--checklist_13_rev2.html
    |   |-- checklist14
    |   |   |-- checklist14.config
    |   |   |-- checklist14.html
    |   |   |-- checklist14.html~
    |   |   `-- rev5
    |   |       |-- rev5.config
    |   |       |-- checklist_14_rev5.html
    |   |       `-- rev5.html~
```

The same expected output should happend for all rev*.html files only inside the rev* folders.

Comment: ⑴ You want to rename the `.html` files … by its previous two directory names, but the `.html` file under `checklist13` gets renamed to `checklist_13_…`. What are the rules for changing `checklist13` to `checklist_13`? ⑵ Will the `.html` file always have the same name as the directory (e.g., `rev2/rev2.html`), or can there be a `rev2/foo.html`? ⑶ If the `.html` file under `rev2` is `rev2/foo.html`, should it be renamed to `checklist_13_rev2.html` or `checklist_13_foo.html`? ⑷ Can there be subdirectories in the `rev…` directories?  Can there be `.html` files in them?  How should they be handled?

Comment: yes underscorE should be added between two directory names and the .html file will always have the same name as directory (i.e rev2/rev2.html).so now the file should be renamed as checklist13_rev2.html.There wont be any sub directories under rev_.Only html files lie under rev* folders. @Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner, using a combination of `find`, `basename`, and `dirname`:

```
find . -regex '.*/rev[0-9]+/rev[0-9]+.html' -exec sh -c 'mv -iv {} $(dirname {})/$(basename $(dirname $(dirname {})))_$(basename $(dirname {})).html' \;
```

It basically uses find regex to get paths ending in rev#/rev#.html, and constructs the new name using combinations `dirname` and `basename` to extract the names of the parent directory and parent directory's parent directory.

Comment: Please use `mv -i` for mass renames like this, to prevent files being silently overwritten if something goes wrong.

Comment: @GordonDavisson good point, edited